# What is wrong with this PHP code to display a list of user's friends who use app?

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

Here is the code which is not working. I want to display a list of the current user's friends who also use app my app. I am able to get the JSON file manually by typing the variable $url into the browser and replacing the access token variable with the access token printed on the page. I have removed some details for security reasons.

```
<?php
require 'fb/facebook.php';

$fbconfig['appUrl'] = "REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY"; 

// Create An instance of our Facebook Application.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY',
  'secret' => 'REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY',
  'cookies' => 'true',
));

// Get the app User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
    try {
        // If the user has been authenticated then proceed
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

// If the user is authenticated then generate the variable for the logout URL
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Friend's JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $user_profile['name'] . " is connected.";
echo "<br />Access token: " . $access_token;

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())&access_token=" . $access_token;
$json = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['data']['name'];
echo $array['data']['uid'];
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php  
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['appUrl']));
  print "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
}
?>
```

These two lines is all that is displayed:

```
echo $user_profile['name'] . " is connected.";
echo "<br />Access token: " . $access_token;
```

Why do you think it is not working? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using the facebook-api , why are you using `file_get_content`?

Comment: I am doing that because the url returns a JSON file which needs to be read.

Comment: Let's debug your code , try adding `var_dump($json)` after `$json = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);`

Comment: That’s not an answer to that question at all. You can comfortably use the Facebook::api method to make the same request, and you will not even have to decode it yourself, but get the data as a PHP array straight away. And btw., “it’s not working” is not a useful problem description.

Comment: When I do that the facebook "Something went wrong" page appears under the name and access token. What do you think could be causing this?

Comment: If you're using API , you don't need to use `file_get_content`. API meant to make your life much easier. Look for that part `Get the User's name using FQL and print it` at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
Edit your code and update us with your results.

Comment: I replaced the code with this:$friender = $facebook->api('/fql?q=SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=214795698587233 and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())','GET');
echo "Name: " . $friender['name'];. But it does not work; It just prints "Name: "

Comment: I got it working by doing this instead: $fql = 'SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=214795698587233 and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                           'method' => 'fql.query',
                           'query' => $fql,
                         ));
echo 'Name: ' . $ret_obj[0]['name'];. Would I need to do a foreach construct to print the name if there is more than one friend using the app? Thank you very much.

Comment: **[is_app_user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) is bool** Indicates whether the user being queried has logged in to the current application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that I'm using to list of user's friends who use that app:

```
$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user = 1"));
```

`var_dump` returns:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uid"]=>
    string(15) "100000670846118"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uid"]=>
    string(15) "100001811974704"
  }
  …
}
```